# Pictures of Different Coordinate Systems in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, mathematical-physics, coordinate-systems

In General Relativity by Woodhouse there are the three following diagrams in Chapter 9 about Black Holes. Despite a (very brief) description of these diagrams in the book itself, I am struggling to understand what they exactly correspond to? Does anyone have good way of looking at how these diagrams help convey a) the properties of the particular coordinate system and b) a understanding of how black holes work in the particular coordinate system being looked at.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Crossposted to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3053022/11127